# Issue with callback inside class

Tags: php

I am trying to bind arbitrary number of parameters to a prepared statement and I cannot seem to get `call_user_func_array()` working for the life of me.

code, where I am having the issue:

```
$q = $this -> dbc -> prepare( $query );

    if ( $params ){
        call_user_func_array( array( &$q,  "bind_param" ) , array_merge( array( $types ), refValues( $params ) ) );
    }
```

I get error like this:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\apache2\htdocs\project\php_lib\cls_Main.php
>   on line 38

EDIT: Fixed thanks to answer.

Final method here:

```
 public function qry( $query, $params = null ){
    if ( is_array( $params ) ){
        if ( substr_count( $query, "?") != count($params) ){
            error("Parameters amount does not match query!");
        }

        $types = "";

        foreach( $params as $parameter ) {

            $t = substr( gettype( $parameter ), 0, 1 );

            if ( in_array( $t , array( "i", "s", "d" ) ) ){
                $types .= $t;
            } else {
                error( "Invalid parameter type: $t !" );
            }

        }

    }

    $q = $this -> dbc -> prepare( $query );

    if ( $q === false ){
        error( "Error in SQL statement: " . $this -> dbc -> error  );
    }

    if ( $params ){
        call_user_func_array( array( $q,  "bind_param" ) , array_merge( array( $types ), refValues( $params ) ) );
    }

    $q -> execute();

    $result = $q -> get_result();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Objects are always passed by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter should be an object, not a reference to an object, so no `&`:

```
 call_user_func_array( array( $q,  "bind_param" ) , array_merge( array( $types ), refValues( $params ) ) );
```

Comment: Thank you! I had it like that initially but kept getting errors. Put it back, same error, var dumped $q and found out prepare returned false. Turned out I had a typo in my query! oh stupid me!